# Joining two lists of objects in java

Tags: java, list, class, join, append

I have a class of instances which follows:

```
package com.sample;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement (name = "instance")
public class Instance {

int id;
double startValue;
double endValue;
double duration;
String Code;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
@XmlElement (name = "ID")
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public double getStart() {
    return startValue;
}
@XmlElement
public void setStart(double start) {
    this.startValue = start;
}
public double getEnd() {
    return endValue;
}
@XmlElement
public void setEnd(double end) {
    this.endValue = end;
}

public void setDuration() {
    duration = endValue - startValue;
}
public String getCode() {
    return Code;
}
@XmlElement
public void setCode(String code) {
    Code = code;
}

}
```

And each instance object is being mapped to values in a XML file of events through a jaxb unmarshaller. These instance objects are then being stored in list class called Instances as follows:

```
package com.sample;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement (name = "ALL_INSTANCES")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Instances {

@XmlElement(name = "instance")
private List<Instance> instances = null;

public List<Instance> getInstances() {
    return instances;
}
public void setInstances(List<Instance> instances) {
    this.instances = instances;
}

public int getLength() {
    return instances.size();
}

public static List<Instances> getUnion(List<Instances> one, List<Instances>      two) { 
    List<Instances> union = new ArrayList<Instances>(one); 
    union.addAll(two); 
    return union; 
}
}
```

In the main method, im trying to call the getUnion() method of two lists of instances to join into one after ive called the unmarshalling process.

```
Instances ins = (Instances) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
Instances ins1 = (Instances) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file1);
Instances.getUnion(ins, ins1);
```

But saying that I get "The method getUnion(List, List) in the type Instances is not applicable for the arguments (Instances, Instances)". Not sure if im calling this right or designed it right.

Basically, I need a method for my Instances class that joins two Instances together into one List to process.

Thanks.

Comment: It's pretty much exactly what it says - you have a method that takes two `List`s, and you're trying to pass it two `Instances`s, and an `Instances` is not a `List`, so what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method takes two arguments of type `List<Instance>`, not of type `Instances`, which is a bit confusing and you may be better off changing the `getUnion` method. But as it currently stands, you can invoke it like this:

```
Instances ins = (Instances) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
Instances ins1 = (Instances) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file1);
List<Instance> result = Instances.getUnion(ins.getInstances(), ins1.getInstances());
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Overthinking a problem at 5am does not help.